# XNA - Card Game - 3D vs 2D vs Primitives

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, 2d

Hello nice people out there

Currently I'm starting a new project in XNA which will be a card game.
While doing my general preparation and planning, I came up with some questions I couldn't answer with the help of the mighty google.
What is the best way to implement my cards? Since I want to rotate these, they'd have to be somehow displayed 3D.
The game itself will be a static view (camera not moving), including the 3D field and apparantly the cards.
So what options do I have to draw my cards?

I came up with:

- 3D Models (worth?)
- 2D Textures (which can be rotatet in a 3D Space with a world matrix
  in SpriteBatch.Begin())
- Primitives (Create vertices manually and apply a texture)

What would be my best approach?
And how could I e.g. draw a texture on a 2D Sprite's/Vertice's back?

I'd appreciate any help or input.

Comment: This would probably be better asked on the video game development stack exchange: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Personally I'd suggest using a flag (or very thin) 3D plane, and applying your texture to the 3D object. But that's just because I find 3D objects easier to work with than manually transforming 2D textures, or creating primitives manually.